# Vuetify data table, display expanded row without columns

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to construct a data table with expanded rows, where I want the expanded part to take up the full width of the parent row. Unfortunatley the expanded row is automatically divided into columns, so if I add only one `<div>` in the `<template>`, that will be displayed under the first item of the parent row. How do I make the expanded-item take up the full width of the table?

I found a source achieving this, but the syntax is from what I understand not compatible with the version of Vuetify I am using: https://codepen.io/francobao/pen/mqxMKP

This is my component that contains the `<v-data-table>`:

```
<template>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <v-data-table
        :headers="headers"
        hide-default-footer
        item-key="name"
        :items="getServiceProviders"
        show-expand >
        <template v-slot:expanded-item="{ headers, item }" >
            <ServiceProviderDetails :isEditMode="true" :serviceProvider="item" />
        </template>
      </v-data-table>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';
import ServiceProviderDetails from './ServiceProviderDetails';

export default {
  name: 'ServiceProviderTable',
  components: {
    ServiceProviderDetails
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['getServiceProviders'])
  },
  data () {
    return {
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Name',
          value: 'name'
        },
        {
          text: 'Service Provider ID',
          value: 'serviceProviderId'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

This is the component to show in the expanded-row:

```
<template>
  <div class="row sp-details">
    <div class="col-4 text-right"><span>Name:</span></div>
    <div class="col-4"><input class="details-input" type="text" v-model="details.name" /></div>
    <div class="col-4"></div>
    <div class="col-4 text-right"><span>PortalUrl:</span></div>
    <div class="col-4"><input class="details-input" type="text" v-model="details.portalUrl" /></div>
    <div class="col-4"></div>
    <div class="col-4 text-right"><span>SupplierId:</span></div>
    <div class="col-4"><input class="details-input" type="text"  v-model="details.supplierId" /></div>
    <div class="col-4"></div>
    <div class="col-4 text-right"><p>Integration Enabled:</p></div>
    <div class="col-4 text-left">
      <span class="integration-switch" v-on:click="toggleIntegration(true)" ><input :checked="details.integrationEnabled" type="radio" />Yes</span>
      <span class="integration-switch" v-on:click="toggleIntegration(false)" ><input :checked="!details.integrationEnabled" type="radio" />No</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4"></div>
    <div class="col-8 offset-4 text-left">
      <v-btn class="mr-2" color="secondary" :checked="details.integrationEnabled" v-on:click="$emit('cancel')">Cancel</v-btn>
      <v-btn color="primary" v-on:click="$emit('save', details)">Save</v-btn>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'ServiceProviderDetails',
  props: \[ 'isEditMode', 'serviceProvider' \],
  data () {
    return {
      details: {
        name: '',
        portalUrl: '',
        supplierId: '',
        integrationEnabled: false
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    if(this.isEditMode){
      this.details = this.serviceProvider;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleIntegration(isEnabled) {
      this.details.integrationEnabled = isEnabled;
    }
  },
  watch: {
    serviceProvider: function() {
      console.log('in serviceprovider')
      if(this.isEditMode){
        console.log(this.serviceProvider)
        this.details = this.serviceProvider;
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

This is what the table header, first row and expanded row looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expanded-item slot accepts 2 params: `{ headers, item }`. Pass the length of headers as a prop to the component to determine the `colspan=` for the td that wraps the `expanded-item` template...

```
    <template v-slot:expanded-item="{ headers, item }" >
        <ServiceProviderDetails :isEditMode="true" :serviceProvider="item" :colspan="headers.length" />
    </template>
```

ServiceProviderDetails component...

```
<template>
  <td :colspan="colspan">
   <div class="row sp-details">
    <div class="col-4 text-right"><span>Name:</span></div>
    <div class="col-4"><input class="details-input" type="text" v-model="details.name" /></div>
    <div class="col-4"></div>
    <div class="col-4 text-right"><span>PortalUrl:</span></div>
    <div class="col-4"><input class="details-input" type="text" v-model="details.portalUrl" /></div>
    <div class="col-4"></div>
    <div class="col-4 text-right"><span>SupplierId:</span></div>
    <div class="col-4"><input class="details-input" type="text"  v-model="details.supplierId" /></div>
    <div class="col-4"></div>
    <div class="col-4 text-right"><p>Integration Enabled:</p></div>
    <div class="col-4 text-left">
      <span class="integration-switch" v-on:click="toggleIntegration(true)" ><input :checked="details.integrationEnabled" type="radio" />Yes</span>
      <span class="integration-switch" v-on:click="toggleIntegration(false)" ><input :checked="!details.integrationEnabled" type="radio" />No</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4"></div>
    <div class="col-8 offset-4 text-left">
      <v-btn class="mr-2" color="secondary" :checked="details.integrationEnabled" v-on:click="$emit('cancel')">Cancel</v-btn>
      <v-btn color="primary" v-on:click="$emit('save', details)">Save</v-btn>
    </div>
   </div>
  </td>
</template>


export default {
  name: 'ServiceProviderDetails',
  props: \[ 'isEditMode', 'serviceProvider', 'colspan' \],
  data () {
    return {
      details: {
        name: '',
        portalUrl: '',
        supplierId: '',
        integrationEnabled: false
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    if(this.isEditMode){
      this.details = this.serviceProvider;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleIntegration(isEnabled) {
      this.details.integrationEnabled = isEnabled;
    }
  },
  watch: {
    serviceProvider: function() {
      console.log('in serviceprovider')
      if(this.isEditMode){
        console.log(this.serviceProvider)
        this.details = this.serviceProvider;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Demo: https://codeply.com/p/qAbvfBn8ut